# Как вызвать функцию (каждый раз возвращает разные значения), в теле цикла несколько раз, чтобы возвращенное значение менялось? Python

Tags: python, функции, циклы

Как вызвать функцию `gen_prog()`, с разными выходными значениями в теле цикла функции `add_all()`?

```
import random
import math

n = 513
a = []
b = [str(x) for x in str(n)]
all_var = []

def gen_prog():
    '''Генерирует новую комбинацию из чисел в "n".'''
    while True:
        z = random.choice(b)
        if z not in a:
            a.append(z)
        if len(a) == len(b):
            break

    return ''.join(a)


def add_all():
    '''Должна добавлять сгенерированную ранее комбинацию в список "all_var".
    Цикл длится до тех пор, пока все возможные значения не будут добавлены в список "all_var".
    Цикл бесконечный, так как значение "y" в теле цикла всегда равно одному и тому же.'''
    while len(all_var) != math.factorial(len(b)):
        y = gen_prog()
        if y not in all_var:
            all_var.append(y)

add_all()
```

Проблема в том, что в цикле функции `add_all()` значение `y` всегда равно одному и тому же. Соответственно значение `y` будет добавлено в список `all_var` только один раз, а затем условие `if y not in all_var:` будет соблюдено и цикл станет бесконечным. Чтобы этого не произошло нужно чтобы функция `gen_prog`, значение которой присвоено `y`, каждый раз генерировала новые значения. Сама по себе функция `gen_prog` работает исправно, однако если она находится в цикле, ее значение всегда равно одному и тому же числу.

Comment: А в чём вопрос? Вроде с виду должно работать. Если поведение функции отличается от ожидаемого, пишите подробности в вопросе.

Comment: Приведите пример того, что вы подаёте на вход и того, что Вы ожидаете на выходе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в использовании глобальной переменной `a`.

После первого вызова она заполнена, и последующие вызовы всегда генерируют то же значение. Сделайте `a` локальной:

```
def gen_prog():
    '''Генерирует новую комбинацию из чисел в "n".'''
    a = []
    while True:
        z = random.choice(b)
        if z not in a:
            a.append(z)
        if len(a) == len(b):
            break

    return ''.join(a)
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы!